# property doesn't exist on interface type

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have implemented an object on the server side (asp.net webapi) controller that contains `boolean` value and `IEnumerable` list. The controller method returns this object. I have also implemented an interface on the client side angular to match the object. However I am getting error:

> `documentDetails` does not contain a property `documentType`.

Not sure why I am getting this error when the interface has it.

Server Side:

```
public class DocumentTypeViewModel {
  public IEnumerable<DOCUMENT_TYPE> documentType;
  public bool canView {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public DocumentTypeViewModel GetDocumentTypes() {
  var documentTypeViewModel = new DocumentTypeViewModel() {
    canView = (IoC.Resolve<IClientAuthorizationService>().Authorize("Put", "ResearchPanel") == AuthAccessLevel.Full),
    documentType = IoC.Resolve<IRepo<DOCUMENT_TYPE>>().GetAll().Where(x => x.IS_ACTIVE)
      .OrderBy(t => t.SORT_ORDER)
  };
  return documentTypeViewModel;
}
```

If you see below `documentDetails` is declared of the type `IDocumentTypes` and  also initialized.

```
export interface IDocumentTypes {
  canView: boolean;
  documentType: any;
}

documentDetails: IDocumentTypes[] = [{
  canView: false,
  documentType: null
}];

this.documentService.getDocumentTypes()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.documentDetails = data;
      this.DocumentTypes = this.documentDetails.documentType.filter(x => x.IS_ACTIVE)
        .map(o => {
          return new ListItem(o['ID'], o['NAME'], true)
        });
      this.SelectedDocTypeIds = this.DocumentTypes.map(o => {
        return o['value']
      });
      this.populateStrategies();
    },
    err => {
      this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
    },
    () => {})
```

Screenshot - `console.log(this.DocumentDetails)`

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you log `data` to the console in the `subscribe` block?

Comment: I have updated the post with the screenshot

Comment: Please provide a sample stackblitz replicating this issue. I don't see any specific issue with your code apart from the usual indentation and naming conventions.

Comment: Here you go https://angular-bbqivx.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

`this.documentDetails` is an Array. The `documentType` Object is present at the 0th index of that array.

So you'll have to access it like this: `this.documentDetails[0].documentType.(...)`

Also, you're trying to access properties that don't really exist on the Objects in the `documentType` Array.

Give this code a try. It should work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export interface IDocumentTypes {
  canView: boolean;
  documentType: any;
}

class ListItem {
  value: number;
  text: string;
  selected: boolean;

  constructor(value: number, text: string, selected: boolean) {
    this.value = value;
    this.text = text;
    this.selected = selected;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  documentDetails: IDocumentTypes[] = [{ canView: false, documentType: null }];
  DocumentTypes: Array<ListItem> = new Array<ListItem>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadDocuments();
  }

  private loadDocuments() {
    this.documentDetails = documents;
    this.DocumentTypes = this.documentDetails[0].documentType.filter(x => x.IsActive)
      .map(o => { return new ListItem(o['DocumentTypeId'], o['Name'], true) });
  }
}
```